# Список всех установленных программ на компьютере, их директория и исполняемый файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, ос

Я пишу код, который должен сопоставлять русское слово и названия приложений и запускать самое подходящее по названию. В принципе тут проблем нету, есть такой код для сопоставления:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from transliterate import translit

russian_word = translit(input(), 'ru', reversed=True)
data = {'name': '', 'percent': 0}

for app in installed_apps:
    percentage = fuzz.ratio(app[:-4], russian_word)
    if percentage > data['percent']:
        data['percent'] = percentage
        data['name'] = app[:-4]

print(data['name'], data['percent'])
```

Но вот с получением списка установленных приложений и директории исполняемого файла были проблемы. Очень долго пытался получить информацию от чата gpt, но всё мимо. Были такие варианты кода: С помощью `winapps`, `winreg`, `shutil`, `pywin32` или просто с помощью `os`. Но всё что я не пробовал, всё работало неполноценно, либо список программ был не полный, либо у большинства программ не находило директорию, либо наводило вообще на все файлы (включая деинсталятор).

То-есть какая вообще **идея**, нужно находить **исполняемый файл** запуска приложения, которое было установлено с помощью любого установщика (setup с интернета, steam, epic games, microsoft store), и запускать его, зная только его примерное название. Если короче, то получить список установленных приложений и прямые пути для их запуска.

**P.S** Операционная система: **Windows**

Comment: Вот на английском SO пара вариантов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132434/list-of-installed-programs

Comment: Это немного не то, мне еще надо чтобы программа получала прямую директорию к файлу для запуска программы

Comment: Ищите ярлыки в пуске, как это делают запускаторы типа Flow Launcher. Это гораздо проще и у ярлыка есть нормальное читабельное название по которому можно нечеткий поиск делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача не простая, но немного подумав изобрел своеобразный велосипед. Посмотрите, возможно он вас устроит))

```
import os
import win32com.client

def resolve_shortcut(shortcut_path):
    if shortcut_path.lower().endswith((".lnk", ".url")):
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcut_path)
        target_path = os.path.abspath(shortcut.TargetPath)
        _, extension = os.path.splitext(target_path)
        
        # Исключаем unins000.exe, Uninstall.exe, setup.exe из выдачи
        if extension.lower() == ".exe" and os.path.basename(target_path).lower() not in ("unins000.exe", "uninstall.exe", "setup.exe"):
            return target_path
    return None

def get_programs_from_start_menu():
    start_menu_path = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramData'], 'Microsoft', 'Windows', 'Start Menu', 'Programs')
    
    programs = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_menu_path):
        for file in files:
            program_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            programs.append(program_path)

    return programs

# Пример использования
programs = get_programs_from_start_menu()
for program in programs:
    exe_path = resolve_shortcut(program)
    if exe_path is not None:
        print(f"Ярлык: {program}, Путь к .exe: {exe_path}")
```

Дополнение:

```
import os
import win32com.client

def resolve_shortcut(shortcut_path):
    if shortcut_path.lower().endswith((".lnk", ".url")):
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shortcut = shell.CreateShortcut(shortcut_path)
        target_path = os.path.abspath(shortcut.TargetPath)
        _, extension = os.path.splitext(target_path)
        
        # Исключаем unins000.exe и Uninstall.exe и setup.exe
        if extension.lower() == ".exe" and os.path.basename(target_path).lower() not in ("unins000.exe", "uninstall.exe", "setup.exe"):
            return target_path
    return None

def get_shortcuts_from_path(path):
    shortcuts = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            shortcut_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            shortcuts.append(shortcut_path)
    return shortcuts

def get_programs_from_start_menu_and_desktop():
    start_menu_path = os.path.join(os.environ['ProgramData'], 'Microsoft', 'Windows', 'Start Menu', 'Programs')
    desktop_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')
    
    start_menu_shortcuts = get_shortcuts_from_path(start_menu_path)
    desktop_shortcuts = get_shortcuts_from_path(desktop_path)

    return start_menu_shortcuts + desktop_shortcuts

# Пример использования
programs = get_programs_from_start_menu_and_desktop()
for program in programs:
    exe_path = resolve_shortcut(program)
    if exe_path is not None:
        print(f"Ярлык: {program}, Путь к .exe: {exe_path}")
```

Список всех установленных программ:

```
import subprocess

# Команда для получения списка установленных программ в Windows
command = 'wmic product get name'

result = subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True, shell=True)

print(result.stdout)
```

Comment: Код работает, и находит множество программ, но всё-же некоторые нужные программы не находит, такие как `visual studio code`, `opera gx`, многие игры

Comment: Значит эти игры/программы не добавили свои ярлыки в Programs, или при установки вы сказали этим играм/программам не добавлять туда свой ярлык.

Comment: В принципе я думаю, что такой код подойдёт, если вы сможете его дополнить, или скажете как добавить программы.

Comment: Как вариант добавить обход других директорий, например рабочего стола: desktop_path = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Desktop')

Comment: В windows же есть список всех приложений (по крайней мере в windows 11), может можно получить доступ к нему? https://imgur.com/a/V6DjLzK. Например на рабочем столе я обычно не храню ярлыки приложений.

Comment: Список получить не проблема и в 10 версии и любой другой. Что с этим списком дальше делать, как он вам поможет? (Создайте папку с ярлыками на диске как вариант)

Comment: Ну оттуда же можно запускать все эти приложения, может и директорию файла извлечь получится?

Comment: Нет, директорию оттуда не извлечь(во всяком случае я такого способа не знаю). Получить список всех установленных программ - да, путь увы нет.

Comment: Ну в общем спасибо за ответ и потраченное время. Я подожду конца недели и если ничего лучше не ответят, то приму ответ.

Comment: Дополнил ответ. Пример как можно получить список всех программ. Но вот добиться получения пути у меня не получилось, отсюда и мой велосипед.

Answer (score 1):

В виндовс установка программ, абстрактное понятие: инсталятор лишь помещает желательно скомпилированное приложение желательно в папку programm files* (но не обязательно minecraft launcher который помещается куда-то в appdata). Так же взять "выбор пути установки" в инсталяторах, которые по факту могут быть 7zip архивами (то есть в итоге в рандомное место даже на другом диске могут скопироваться два файла типа 'my_cool_app.bat и unins111.ps1'. Следовательно 100% результата не будет. Частичный результат может быть достигнут при помощи сканирования меню пуск, рабочих столов default user & other на предмет наличия ярлыков запуска. (но это не решит проблему с minecraft) следовательно более оптимален вариант создания базы популярных приложений и их текстовой русской интерпритации (к примеру голосом запустить заставку будет прикольно C:...*.scr). Естественно это потребует полного сканирования файловой системы на предмет исполняемых файлов, поиска по базе, и добавления\изменения пути в базу. Но это не решит проблему деинсталяции\реинсталяции с новым путём. Тут возможен третий вариант (костыль): производить поиск исполняемого файла по базе, параллельно ему исспользовать "поиск винды",- пусть эта зараза отрабатывает свой хлеб.

---

текст слишком большой для комма, но на ответ не тянет