Поиск приложения с помощью Python
Здраствуйте! Мне нужно, чтобы програма на Python искала какую-нибудь програму на компе пользователя. Например:
import subprocess


#код для поиска sublime text
#код для поиска sublime text
#код для поиска sublime text

where_is_sublime = '...'
subprocess.run([where_is_sublime])


А чуть подробней можно?

@Amgarak
Я делаю голосового асистента. Мне нужно, чтобы если например пользователь сказал "открой sublime text", то програма нашла где находится sublime text и открыла его

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1552227/562052

@Amgarak Спасибо!
