Не все установленные программы отображаются в списке
Делаю программу на Python. В коде есть функция:
def get_installed_programs():
    programs = {}
    try:
        for app in winapps.list_installed():
            if app.name not in programs:
                version = app.version if app.version else 'Неизвестно'
                install_location = app.install_location if app.install_location else 'Неизвестно'
                install_date = app.install_date.strftime('%d.%m.%Y') if app.install_date else 'Неизвестно'
                programs[app.name] = (version, install_date, install_location)
        return [(name, *details) for name, details in programs.items()]
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Упс!", f"Ошибка получения данных об установленных программах: {str(e)}")
        return []

В программе показывает всего 169 установленных, а в "Программы и компоненты" показывает 195. Как решить?

Этот список установленных программ, мягко говоря, формируется в современных Windows давно уже не так, как это было когда-то. То, что этот модуль для Питон считает установленной программой, давно уже лишь часть более широкого джентльменского набора. Могут буть и другие виды программ. Например, я могу зайти на какой-либо сайт в браузере Microsoft Edge и сделать из него программу. Такая программа будет "проинсталлирована", можно создать для неё ярлык, закрепить на панели задач и в меню Пуск. Но это просто маленькая обёртка для открытия сайта в режиме "киоск" в указанном браузере.

Тут обсуждали проблему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1552227/562052
